# PHP - Creating a directory according to session variable

Tags: php, file, mkdir, directory

I was wondering how to create a directory (on HTML upload button click) with PHP according to a session variable called 'UserID'.

This is what I tried to do:

```
    <?php
    include("login.php");

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <title>FileStore - Upload Files</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">

    <header id="header">


    <div id="header-content">
        <strong><h1>FileStore</h1></strong> Upload multiple files at once!
    </div>

    <div class="login-info" >

    <?php



    if ($isLoggedin === false) {
        echo '  <form action="" method="POST">
                    Username: <input name="username" > 
                    Password: <input type="password" name="password" size="8">
                              <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
                </form>';
        echo "<p align='right'>You are not logged in.</p>";
        echo "<b><a href='registration.php'>Register</a></b>";


    }else{  
        echo $welcomeMsg;
    }   
?>

    </div>


    </header><!-- #header-->

    <section id="middle" align="center">

        <div id="container">

        <br><br>
            <div id="content">
                <strong><h1>Upload files</h1></strong><br><br>

                <div id="upload-file" >

                <?php 


                    include("dbConfig.php");

                    $Username = $_SESSION["username"];


                    //$Password = $_SESSION["password"];

                    $Password = md5($Password);

                    $sql = "SELECT UserID FROM users WHERE Username = '".$Username."' AND Password = '".$Password."'";

                    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

                    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                            $userid = $row['UserID'];

                    }


                    echo $userid;

                    $dirname = $userid;

                    $filename = ("/folder/" . "$dirname" . "/");

                    if (!file_exists($filename))

                    {

                                mkdir("files/'$userid'", 0777);

                    } else {


                    if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {

                        echo "<div id='files_table'><table class='center'.><tr><td>";



                                foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name){

                                move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "files/'".$userid."'{$_FILES['files']['name'][$key]}");

                                echo $_FILES['files']['name'][$key], " uploaded.", "<br>";


                        }
                        echo "</td></tr></table></div><br><br>";
                        }




                    }




                        if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {

                        echo "<div id='files_table'><table class='center'.><tr><td>";



                                foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name){

                                move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "files/'".$userid."'{$_FILES['files']['name'][$key]}");

                                echo $_FILES['files']['name'][$key], " uploaded.", "<br>";


                        }
                        echo "</td></tr></table></div><br><br>";
                        }

                ?>
                    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                            <h1> Select files to upload:</h1>
                            <br>
                            <p>
                                <input type="file" name ="files[]" multiple min="1" /> 
                                <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
                            </p>
                            <br>
                            <h2> You can select multiple files for upload. </h2>

                    </form>

        </div>

            </div><!-- #content-->
        </div><!-- #container-->

        <aside id="sideLeft">

            <div id="menu-x" align="center"><br>
            <strong>Menu</strong><br><br>

                    <div class="menu">
                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="upload.php">Upload</a></li>
                        <li><a href="files.php">Files</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="help.php">Help</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <br style="clear:left"/>
                    </div>

            </div>


        </aside><!-- #sideLeft -->

    </section><!-- #middle-->

    <footer id="footer">
        <strong>FileStore:</strong> A CMT 3315 Project by Brian Livori
    </footer><!-- #footer -->

</div><!-- #wrapper -->

</body>
</html>
```

This does not work. I get the following error messages:

> Notice: Undefined variable: Password in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Task2PHP\final\upload.php on line 70
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: userid in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Task2PHP\final\upload.php on line 83
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: userid in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Task2PHP\final\upload.php on line 85
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: userid in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Task2PHP\final\upload.php on line 93
>
> Warning: mkdir(): File exists in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Task2PHP\final\upload.php on line 93

Any idea how I could do it ?

Comment: you  need to read [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) and check post request is set  before use and last warning is file already exist ..so either delete older file or rename new file

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT UserID FROM users WHERE Username = '".$Username."' AND Password = '".$Password."'";` Please don't do this for a live production site. Of course if it's on your localhost and just learning  then you'll be ok (for now)

Comment: @NullPointer I created a global userid; at the start of the php script, but the folder being created is being called ". Also, it shows up an error if the directory already exists.

Comment: md5 really ? you need to use sha check [this awesome video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RLmuFlDygn0) by [Anthony Ferrara](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/338665/ircmaxell)   ... your code is vulnerable to sql injunction and dont use `mysql_*` function cthere are deprecated use pdo or mysqli instead

Comment: @NullPointer It's just a simple application I'm trying to finish to learn PHP

Comment: @NullPointer Is that video really about using `sha` for password hashing? ;)

Comment: @PeeHaa sorry i missed there i another video for that ...gonna find .. also if you have already link please add here

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the comments below your question about security:

1. `$userid` is not set. That means that your query did not return any rows. You should add error handling to all database calls (which you should change to PDO / mysqli), including the scenario that there is no user found;
2. You check for a directory `/folder/" . "$dirname" . "/"` but then you try to generate a direcory `"files/'$userid'"`. That should be `"/folder/$userid"` or even more consistent `"/folder/'$dirname'"`;
3. I doubt you want to store the files in a folder called `/folder` in the root of the file-system, so you should check that.